# How do I say 'There is always a reason for a drink'?

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation

in Dutch we say 'er is altijd een reden voor een borrel', which I want engraved on a whisky glass for my friend. How do you say 'There is always a reason for a drink' in Latin?

On the internet, I find 'semper enim potum' and I was wondering if this was correct?

Comment: *Semper enim potum* is not correct. Google Translate (if that's the source) practically never produces correct Latin.

Answer (score 8):

Translating as *semper est bibendum* could make a recognizable variant on Horace's famous *nunc est bibendum*, "now is the time to drink" (Ode 1.37).

Answer (score 7):

You give a valuable hint when saying you want this engraved on a whisky glass.
Whisky is derived from Irish *[uisce beatha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uisce_beatha)*, which means *water of life*. This translates into Latin as [**aqua vitae**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aqua_vitae), which is still recognisable in Danish akvavit.

If we replace reason with occasion ([occasio](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Doccasio)), and we modify aqua into *aquae* because it has to be a dative, we're there:

**Semper occasio aquae vitae**.

Proost!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe, "semper est causa ad bibendum."

Comment: Wouldn't it be *causa bibendi*? I've never seen *causa + ad*

Comment: @brianpck. I actually looked this up on PHI shortly after the question was posted. I found a couple of scattered examples of causa + ad + accusative – one in Terence, as I recall. Of course, the genitive is much more common.